# Isotope Filters Break Masonry Layout

Tags: jquery-isotope

I'm integrating Isotope with Foundation 5 for an image gallery, and I'm running into an issue. Using the masonry layout, I have 5 filters: All, Interior, Exterior, Wall, Floor. The first 3 filters layout fine when I click them, but once I click the 'Wall' or 'Floor' filters, all the items are reduced to one column. Additional weird behavior is that when I've selected the 'Wall' or 'Floor' filters, then I click back on the 'Exterior' filter, it also gets reduced to one column. Not until I click on either the 'All' or 'Interior' filters do the columns reform into the masonry layout. Basically, only the first 3 filters work, although the third filter can be problematic as well.

If I change the layout to 'fitRows' all the filters work fine. I'm using media queries to show 5 items across at full width, and 2 items across on mobile layouts.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <dl id="filters" class="sub-nav">
      <dt>Filter:</dt>
      <dd class="active" data-filter="*"><a href="#">All</a></dd>
      <dd data-filter=".int"><a href="#">Interior</a></dd>
      <dd data-filter=".ext"><a href="#">Exterior</a></dd>
      <dd data-filter=".wall"><a href="#">Wall</a></dd>
      <dd data-filter=".floor"><a href="#">Floor</a></dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div id="isoContainer">
        <div class="isoItem int"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem int"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem int"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem floor"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem ext"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem ext"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem wall"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem int"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem wall"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem int"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem wall"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem ext"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem floor"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem ext"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem wall"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div class="isoItem int"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  var $container = $('#isoContainer');
  $(window).load(function(){
    $container.isotope({
      // options
      itemSelector: '.isoItem',
      layoutMode: 'masonry',
      resizable: false, // disable normal resizing    
    });

    // update columnWidth on window resize
    $(window).smartresize(function(){
      $container.isotope({
        masonry: { columnWidth: 182 }
      });
    });

    $('#filters').on( 'click', 'dd', function( event ) {
      var filtr = $(this).attr('data-filter');

        $container.isotope({ filter: filtr });

    });
  });
    $('#filters dd').click(function(){
    $('#filters dd.active').removeClass('active');
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
  });

</script>
```